# one side video in linphone 3.5.2 for android

Tags: android, video, linphone

I have integrated linphone 3.5.2 in my vvoip application. I am checking video call between linphone on windows and my application with h.263 or VP8 codec and PCMA codec.
Speech working fine on both end but i facing a problem in video,
On my application both side video is played but at remote end (on linphone windows) only self view is display. My view at remote side is corrupted (same as blank window).

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing within LAN try disabling the stun server setting.